# WooCommerce API for mobile App

Tags: android, wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

i am planning to develop a native mobile Android App for WooCommerce shops.

I had a look at their REST API documentation here: http://docs.woocommercev2.apiary.io/
I already started to test it but when i do different calls

`GET /orders` let's say it returns all the orders of the shop.

Does anyone have any idea how can i develop a enduser app using their API.

for example:

```
GET /products
```

`PUT /order` (create a order for the logged in User)

`GET /order` (get orders of the logged in User)

Any idea is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U got any solutions?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar the only solution is to write it all by yourself by using woocommerce hooks when you can, i didn't found any other solution :/

Comment: Hay I found the answer using oAuth.. I will update as soon as I go home.. not all the functionality.. however we can get most of then we need.

Comment: user1305626: Did you make android app using REST API? I am getting Signature issue in Android app. Can you let me know how to generate Signature for WooCommerce REST API? Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948988/invalid-signature-provided-signature-does-not-match-woocommerce-rest-api-calli

Comment: @DilipRajkumar please send me solution too..

Comment: Enable API in backend -> Using lighweight middleware -> Connect server -> Return JSON data to your app. Otherwise try readily built api in apphitect   http://www.apphitect.ae/mobile-commerce-app.php

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this steps

First thing you can Enable Api for woocommerce from the backend – http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce use this link, which has all the methods to interacting with woocommerce. Otherwise using lightweight middleware, it help to connect woocommerce server & return JSON data to your app.

Write a service using ionic framework and talk to your thin middleware client. Do not forget to cache the data (using local storage), so that you don’t hit the server all the time. - Contus M Comm

Answer (score 2):

For `http` (and not ssl protocol such as `https` ) request, you must use from **OAthu 1.0a** authenticate framework.
There are many libraries for **oauth 1.0a** in java,
i'm use from **[scribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava)**

So, do the following steps:

1. In **`app/build.gradle`** in dependency scop add this:

   `compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.5'`
2. New class as **WoocommerceApi** for provider of **OAuth service**.
   important. You must use a
   `public` class in DefaultApi10a for implementing oauth provider

   ```
   public static class WooCommerceApi extends org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a {

       @Override
       public org.scribe.model.Verb getRequestTokenVerb()
       {
           return org.scribe.model.Verb.POST;
       }

       @Override
       public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
           return "http://www.your-domain.com/wc-auth/authorize";
       }

       @Override
       public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
           return "none";
       }

       @Override
       public String getAuthorizationUrl(org.scribe.model.Token requestToken) {
           return "none";
       }
   }
   ```
3. And you **Must make request in `Thread` or `AsyncTask`**

   ```
   String restURL = "http://www.your-domain.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/";
   OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(WooCommerceApi.class)
        .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY) //Your Consumer key
        .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET) //Your Consumer secret
        .scope("API.Public") //fixed
        .signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString)
        .build();
   OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, restURL);
   // for POST requests 
   // OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, restURL); 
   // request.addBodyParameter(YOUR_PARAM_KEY, YOUR_VALUE);
   // or 
   // request.addPayload(YOUR_JSON);
   Token accessToken = new Token("", ""); //not required for context.io
   service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
   Response response = request.send();
   Log.d("OAuthTask",response.getBody());
   ```

Comment: Your above answer was perfect and to the point. One more thing I need to ask that, You've written the above solution for GET Method only. What should we do if we want to POST and add any parameter? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey! can you explain your answer more actually i'm trying to implement woo commerce API but not getting data in my app. Implementing 1.0 authentication

Comment: @PankajLilan I updated my answer... you can use request.addpayload() method

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. My query is can I do it with retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the expected data format is JSON only (in contrast with the previous XML or Json) but there is unfortunately no further explanation on which data structure is expected for each endpoint.

Here's the only example of a POST request format from the current documentation for creating a coupon:

REST request URI

```
POST http://private-anon-0fe404a22-woocommercev2.apiary-mock.com/coupons?fields=id,code&filter=filter[limit]=100&page=2
```

Java code (pasted from the documentation)

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Entity payload = Entity.json("{  'coupon': {    'code': 'autumn-is-coming',    'type': 'fixed_cart',    'amount': '4.00',    'individual_use': true,    'description': ''  }}");
Response response = client.target("http://private-anon-0fe404a22-woocommercev2.apiary-mock.com")
  .path("/coupons{?fields,filter,page}")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
  .post(payload);

System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Json response

```
{
  "coupon": {
    "id": 21548,
    "code": "augustheat",
    "type": "fixed_cart",
    "created_at": "2014-08-30T19:25:48Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-08-30T19:25:48Z",
    "amount": "5.00",
    "individual_use": false,
    "product_ids": [],
    "exclude_product_ids": [],
    "usage_limit": null,
    "usage_limit_per_user": null,
    "limit_usage_to_x_items": 0,
    "usage_count": 0,
    "expiry_date": "2014-08-30T21:22:13Z",
    "apply_before_tax": true,
    "enable_free_shipping": false,
    "product_category_ids": [],
    "exclude_product_category_ids": [],
    "exclude_sale_items": false,
    "minimum_amount": "0.00",
    "maximum_amount": "0.00",
    "customer_emails": [],
    "description": "Beat the August heat with $5 off your purchase!"
  }
}
```

http://docs.woocommercev2.apiary.io/#reference/coupons/coupons-collection/create-a-coupon

Considering the API is claimed to be accepting POST requests for all relevant endpoints this should be possible with a shopping order.

Comment: It also looks like the documentation is under construction so there might be other examples in the near future.

I am also figuring the REST API out and will update my answer if I make any progress.

This is more suited as a comment but I cannot comment yet.

Comment: TNTanuki Thanks for the reply but what i was pointing out was an API for the enduser because this way you have access in every resource of the system. I was thinking for an API that a single user can login and purchase on using his shopping card and his details.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the credential keys to be available on the client side ?

If your concern is about being logged in, you don't need to be logged in when using the API -I just tried-.

I am not sure what your original question is now. Maybe can you rephrase it now that you have spent a few days working on it ? I am myself learning this API and made some progress.

Answer (score -1):

One can use Plug and play solutions AKA App builders such as [Appmaker.xyz](https://appmaker.xyz) in order to create an end-user app.

Comment: The question is how to build own native app for woo commerce . He was not looking for ready made apps and stack over flow is not a platform to promote commercial products I think .