# How to use Woocommerce api in android app with customer key and customer secret keys of woocommerce wordpress website

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am making android application for a wordpress website, website has installed woocommerce, and woocommerce has features like wp rest api, so that we can access data by having it's api's of our website.
but is there anyone who can tell me about how can to make woocommerce api and android connection and make my app synced with website.

Comment: see my answer [here : WooCommerce API for mobile App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489565/woocommerce-api-for-mobile-app/41526167#41526167)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by enabling woocommerce API in wordpress. by using below key u can authenticate urself to POST or GET something through ur mobile apps.

[This is the documentation of the api on how to generate consumer key and secret key](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)

[Check it here on the coding to POST or GET from ur mobile apps](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#create-a-product)