# How to call WooCommerce API from android studio using Volley library?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, android-volley

I am new to Android and I am using JAVA and Android studio. I have to use the WooCommerce API to get the list of all orders:

```
wp-json/wc/v2/orders
```

Is this possible using the volley library and if yes, how can I call this and get the response (I have my `client_id` and `client_secret`)?

Here is my activity page:

```
public class YourOrders extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textViewback;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_orders);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    textViewback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewback);
    textViewback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489565/woocommerce-api-for-mobile-app

Comment: I have gone through but it is not clear to me. @Mohamed

Comment: what is the return of your web service ? JSON or xml !!

Comment: Response as JSON @Mohamed

Comment: just googling for Android JSON parsing using Volley and you will get how to parse json with volley like this post https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String url = "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=abc";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    textViewback.setText("Response: " + response.toString()); 
    }
},  

   new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO: Handle error

}
});
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thankypou ,it solved the problem as consumer_key and consumer_secret served as for the purpose for authentication .